# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError when I try to run Django framework?

Tags: python, django, module, directory, frameworks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC8Kz.png)
I want to start Django framework learning but whenever I run python manage.py runserver ===>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:\Users\LENOVO'
PS C:\Users\LENOVO\Dev\cfeproj>

I dont know what to configure from here, my C drive became a module? Dont know how that happened ={ really frustrating ,i keep failing. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Its probably a missing file called cfeproj. (with no extensions). Try to find if the file is required and what its role is. If it's not required, you can remove it.

Comment: Hi ,thank you for replying, i really appreciate it. Why "No module named 'C:\Users\LENOVO' " ? I totally cannot understand this statement. Help =(

Comment: Hi fidx. Do you have a screenshot of the error message and post it here. Thanks!

Comment: yes ,as here -->  https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC8Kz.png

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok, I have looked at your screenshot. It is referring to the folder, C:\Users\LENOVO. Does your django-admin run properly such as starting the local server, compiling, etc?

Comment: Hi Ezani, i got it right this time, however having trouble with 'powershell.exe' now haha..it's endless troubles

Comment: Launching subshell in virtual environment...
'powershell.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. ==> how to solve this?